# How is File.open implemented in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file, file-io

I tried finding how `File.open()` was implemented but I couldn't find it while grepping around in the code I got from https://github.com/ruby/ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `File::open`, it is inherited from `IO`. So, you need to look for `IO::open`.

In general, I recommend using the Rubinius source code for this. It is much better organized and much better documented than YARV's source code, and most importantly: it is mostly written in Ruby, whereas in YARV the entire language, the entire core library and significant portions of the standard library are written in C.

That being said, [the implementation of `IO::open` is completely and utterly boring](https://GitHub.Com/Rubinius/Rubinius/blob/master/kernel/common/io.rb#L211-225). It just does the obvious thing:

```
def self.open(*args)
  io = new(*args)

  return io unless block_given?

  begin
    yield io
  ensure
    begin
      io.close unless io.closed?
    rescue StandardError
      # nothing, just swallow them.
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The `File` class is a C module, not a Ruby one.  So, you won't find Ruby code for it.

Looks like it lives in `file.c` in the root folder.  The module includes the `IO` module, which is another C module and lives in `io.c` in the same location.  Look for functions in there whose names start with `rb_file_open`.